# Update não gera erros mas não atualiza a tabela

Tags: php, sql-update

Estou com um problema, e venho pedir ajuda.
Este tenho esse código que se refere a um formulario de cadastro completo de clientes para o meu site
O Insert feito, funciona perfeitamente e grava as informações no banco de dados
já o update quando vou editar um desses contatos não atualiza as informações.
Seré que algum de vocês pode me ajudar a identificar o que ha de errado, uma vez que ele não retorna erro algum, apenas não funciona.

```
if($_POST["acao"]=="novo"){

    $DATANASC     = $_POST["data_nascimento"];
    $NOME         = $_POST["nome"];
    $RESPONSAVEL  = $_POST["responsavel"];
    $SEXO         = $_POST["sexo"];
    $EMPRESA      = $_POST["empresa"];
    $RG           = $_POST["rg"];
    $CPF          = $_POST["cpf"];
    $CNPJ         = $_POST["cnpj"];
    $IE           = $_POST["ie"];
    $TEL1         = $_POST["telefone"];
    $TEL2         = $_POST["telefone_2"];
    $CEL1         = $_POST["celular"];
    $CEL2         = $_POST["celular_2"];
    $EMAIL        = $_POST["email"];
    $SENHA        = sha1($_POST["senha"]);
    $CEP          = $_POST["cep"];
    $ENDERECO     = $_POST["endereco"];
    $NUMERO       = $_POST["numero"];
    $BAIRRO       = $_POST["bairro"];
    $CIDADE       = $_POST["cidade"];
    $UF           = $_POST["uf"];
    $COMPLEMENTO  = $_POST["complemento"];
    $OBS          = $_POST["obs"];
    $IBGE         = $_POST["ibge"];
    $FACEBOOK     = $_POST["facebook"];
    $CATEGORIA    = $_POST["Categoria"];
    $nome_fantasia    = $_POST["nome_fantasia"];

    if($CNPJ > 0) $Q = "OR cnpj = '".$CNPJ."'";
    if($CPF > 0) $Q = "OR cpf = '".$CPF."'";

    $QueryClientCons = mysql_query("SELECT nome, email, cpf, cnpj, Categoria FROM clientes WHERE nome = '".$NOME."' ".$Q." OR email = '".$EMAIL."'"); 

//RESPONDENDO CHECAGEM
if(mysql_num_rows($QueryClientCons)>0){

$DADOSIGUAIS = mysql_fetch_array($QueryClientCons);

echo "<div class='warning'>Este Cliente já existe! (".$DADOSIGUAIS["nome"]." ".$DADOSIGUAIS["email"]." ".$DADOSIGUAIS["cpf"]." ".$DADOSIGUAIS["cnpj"]." ".$DADOSIGUAIS["Categoria"].")</div>";

}else{

//inserindo registros no banco de dados
$QueryClientUP = mysql_query("INSERT INTO clientes (data_cadastrada, data_nascimento, nome, nome_fantasia, responsavel, sexo, empresa, rg, cpf, cnpj, inscricao_estadual, telefone, telefone_2, celular, celular_2, email, senha, cep, ibge, endereco, numero, bairro, cidade, uf, complemento, Categoria, origem, obs, facebook)  VALUES (NOW(), '".$DATANASC."', '".$NOME."', '".$nome_fantasia."', '".$RESPONSAVEL."', '".$SEXO."', '".$EMPRESA."', '".$RG."', '".$CPF."', '".$CNPJ."','".$IE."', '".$TEL1."', '".$TEL2."', '".$CEL1."', '".$CEL2."', '".$EMAIL."' , '".$SENHA."' , '".$CEP."' , '".$IBGE."' , '".$ENDERECO."' , '".$NUMERO."' , '".$BAIRRO."' , '".$CIDADE."' , '".$UF."' , '".$COMPLEMENTO."', '".$CATEGORIA."', '".$ORIGEM."', '".$OBS."', '".$FACEBOOK."')") or die (mysql_error());

$Ultimo = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(id) AS ULTIMON FROM clientes");
$Ultimo = mysql_fetch_array($Ultimo);
$ID = $Ultimo["ULTIMON"];

$_POST["cnpj"] = str_replace(".", "", $_POST["cnpj"]);  
$_POST["cnpj"] = str_replace("-", "", $_POST["cnpj"]);
$_POST["cnpj"] = str_replace("/", "", $_POST["cnpj"]);

$_POST["cpf"] = str_replace(".", "", $_POST["cpf"]);
$_POST["cpf"] = str_replace("-", "", $_POST["cpf"]);

$_POST["cep"] = str_replace("-", "", $_POST["cep"]);


$TEL1 = str_replace("(", "", $TEL1);
$TEL1 = str_replace(")", "", $TEL1);    
$TEL1 = str_replace("-", "", $TEL1);
$TEL1 = str_replace(" ", "", $TEL1);


$TEL2 = str_replace("(", "", $TEL2);
$TEL2 = str_replace(")", "", $TEL2);    
$TEL2 = str_replace("-", "", $TEL2);
$TEL2 = str_replace(" ", "", $TEL2);


$CEL1 = str_replace("(", "", $CEL1);
$CEL1 = str_replace(")", "", $CEL1);    
$CEL1 = str_replace("-", "", $CEL1);
$CEL1 = str_replace(" ", "", $CEL1);


if ( $_POST[ "cnpj" ] > 0 ) {
    $CPF_CNPJ = $_POST["cnpj"];
    $T_pessoa = "j";
    $RG_IE = $_POST["ie"];
} else {
    $CPF_CNPJ = $_POST["cpf"];
    $T_pessoa = "f";
    $RG_IE = $_POST["rg"];
}

$BD_USR_SINGLE = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO integre_single_clientes
(codigo, nome_razao, apelido_fantasia, cpf_cnpj, rg_ie, tipo_pessoa, data_nascimento, email, email_danfe, data_cadastro, tipo_endereco, endereco, numero, bairro, codigo_ibge, desc_municip, cep, telefone, celular, tel_comer, obs, flag_3)
VALUES ('".$ID."', '".$NOME."', '".$NOME."', '".$CPF_CNPJ."', '".$RG_IE."', '".$T_pessoa."', '".$DATANASC."', '".$_POST["email"]."', '".$_POST["email"]."', NOW(), 'Residencial', '".$_POST["endereco"]."', '".$_POST["numero"]."',  '".$_POST["bairro"]."', '".$_POST["ibge"]."', '".$_POST["cidade"]."', '".$_POST["cep"]."', '".$TEL1."', '".$CEL1."',  '".$TEL2."', '".$OBS."', '0')");


}

}elseif($_POST["acao"]=="editar"){

if ($_POST["senha"] <> ""){ $SENHA = "senha = '".sha1($_POST["senha"])."',"; }
if ($_POST["data_cadastrada"] > 0){}else{ $DATACASD = "data_cadastrada = NOW(),"; }

$ID           = $_POST["id"];
$DATANASC     = $_POST["data_nascimento"];
$NOME         = $_POST["nome"];
$RESPONSAVEL  = $_POST["responsavel"];
$SEXO         = $_POST["sexo"];
$EMPRESA      = $_POST["empresa"];
$RG           = $_POST["rg"];
$CPF          = $_POST["cpf"];
$CNPJ         = $_POST["cnpj"];
$IE           = $_POST["ie"];
$TEL1         = $_POST["telefone"];
$TEL2         = $_POST["telefone_2"];
$CEL1         = $_POST["celular"];
$CEL2         = $_POST["celular_2"];
$EMAIL        = $_POST["email"];
$CEP          = $_POST["cep"];
$ENDERECO     = $_POST["endereco"];
$NUMERO       = $_POST["numero"];
$BAIRRO       = $_POST["bairro"];
$CIDADE       = $_POST["cidade"];
$UF           = $_POST["uf"];
$COMPLEMENTO  = $_POST["complemento"];
$OBS          = $_POST["obs"];
$IBGE         = $_POST["ibge"];
$FACEBOOK     = $_POST["facebook"];
$CATEGORIA    = $_POST["Categoria"];
$nome_fantasia    = $_POST["nome_fantasia"];
$ORIGEM       = $_POST["origem"];   

$NOME = str_replace("'", " ", $NOME);
$ENDERECO = str_replace("'", " ", $ENDERECO);
$BAIRRO = str_replace("'", " ", $BAIRRO);
$CIDADE = str_replace("'", " ", $CIDADE);
$UF = str_replace("'", " ", $UF);
$COMPLEMENTO = str_replace("'", " ", $COMPLEMENTO);

//atualizando registros no banco de dados
$QueryClientUPD = mysql_query("UPDATE clientes SET ".$DATACASD." data_nascimento = '".$DATANASC."', nome = '".$NOME."', , nome_fantasia ='".$nome_fantasia."', responsavel = '".$RESPONSAVEL."', sexo = '".$SEXO."', empresa = '".$EMPRESA ."', rg = '".$RG."',  cpf = '".$CPF."', cnpj = '".$CNPJ."', inscricao_estadual = '".$IE."', telefone = '".$TEL1."', telefone_2 = '".$TEL2."', celular = '".$CEL1."', celular_2 = '".$CEL2."', email = '".$EMAIL."', ".$SENHA." cep = '".$CEP."', ibge = '".$IBGE."', endereco = '".$ENDERECO."', numero = '".$NUMERO."', bairro = '".$BAIRRO."', cidade = '".$CIDADE."', uf = '".$UF."', complemento = '".$COMPLEMENTO."', Categoria = '".$CATEGORIA."', origem = '".$ORIGEM."', obs = '".$OBS."', facebook = '".$FACEBOOK."' WHERE id = '".$ID."'");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltavam nomes de campos, virgulas, e `WHERE` no lugar errado:

```
$QueryClientUPD = mysql_query("
    UPDATE clientes 
    SET 
        data_nascimento = '$DATANASC', 
        nome = '$NOME', 
        nome_fantasia ='$nome_fantasia', 
        responsavel = '$RESPONSAVEL', 
        sexo = '$SEXO', 
        empresa = '$EMPRESA', 
        rg = '$RG',  
        cpf = '$CPF', 
        cnpj = '$CNPJ', 
        inscricao_estadual = '$IE', 
        telefone = '$TEL1', 
        telefone_2 = '$TEL2', 
        celular = '$CEL1', 
        celular_2 = '$CEL2', 
        email = '$EMAIL', 
        senha = $SENHA, 
        cep = '$CEP', 
        ibge = '$IBGE', 
        endereco = '$ENDERECO', 
        numero = '$NUMERO', 
        bairro = '$BAIRRO', 
        cidade = '$CIDADE', 
        uf = '$UF', 
        complemento = '$COMPLEMENTO', 
        Categoria = '$CATEGORIA', 
        origem = '$ORIGEM', 
        obs = '$OBS', 
        facebook = '$FACEBOOK'
    WHERE id = '$ID'"
);
```

Comment: Porra kra, vlw mesmo era exatamente isso, desculpa minha nubagem

Comment: Eu quem agradeço por poder ajudar, acontece as vezes passa algo despercebido